# Remove span element on focus

Tags: jquery, selector, onfocus

I have several Textboxes each with a span element like this:

```
<span class="reqDiv" name="Required">This value is required</span>
<input class="form-control" id="txtAddress" placeholder="Address" type="text" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">

<span class="reqDiv" name="Required">This value is required</span>
<input class="form-control" id="txtZip" placeholder="Zip Code" type="text" maxlength="5">
```

I want to remove the span element of the textbox which is in focus. I tried the following `jquery` code that removes the span element of all textboxes instead of the particular 'on-focus' textbox. How can I achieve it?

The jquery:

```
$("#Offer_Form").find(".form-control").on("focus", function (e) {
        $("span[name='Required']")
    });
```

**EDIT:** This is how I am generating span tag through jquery:

```
var SetErrorStateForControl = function (elemObj, msg) {
        elemObj.closest('div').find($("span[name='Required']")).remove();
        $('<span class="reqDiv" name="Required">' + msg + '</span>').prependTo(elemObj.closest('div'));
    }
```

Comment: Don't remove `span`, hide (toggle) it. When you'll leave the input field without filling it, you'll loose your label!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
$( "input.form-control:text" ).focus(function() {
   $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prev()` method to get the corresponding span of each tag

```
$("#Offer_Form").find(".form-control").on("focus", function(e) {
  $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

Comment: This span appears on my textboxes. I tried your code, but it sticks over there and is overwritten on whatever i enter into the textbox

Answer (score 0):

The `.prev([selector])` method get the immediately preceding sibling

If you want to remove the previous `span` element you can try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".form-control").focus(function(e) {
      $(this).prev('span').remove(); //.prev('span') get the previous span
    });
});
```

Comment: This `prev` thing isn't working. It doesn't remove it

Answer (score 0):

You should use [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function for finding the previous span and  [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function for removing the span. Example is **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8m3o687m/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.form-control').focus(function(e) {
      $(this).prev('span').hide(); // use hide() for hiding
    });
});
```

If you want to remove the span instead of hiding then just use remove() function.

```
$(this).prev('span').remove(); // use remove() for removing
```

Comment: it doesn't remove the span

Comment: @HumaAli Yes its only hiding the `span` if you want to remove then use `remove()` function. I'm updating answer

Comment: It still doesn't remove the span. this line `$(this).prev('span').remove();` isn't working properly

Comment: yes this fiddle works fine but dont know why isnt it working fine in my code. I have eidted my question, with additional information, maybe im doing something wrong in creating the span

Comment: @HumaAli Can you kindly check if jquery is loading properly?

Comment: Yes it is loaded properly

Comment: @HumaAli Ok can you kindly show me all the relevant code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112166/discussion-between-huma-ali-and-mr-developer).